# Problems with CircleTimes and infix notation

Tags: tensors

I am trying to create a function called `TensorBasis` that takes as input a list (thought of as a list of names of basis vectors of a vector space) and an integer `d` and output the lexicographically ordered basis of the `d`-fold tensor product of the vector space with itself.

For instance, the output of `TensorBasis[{v1,v2},2]` should be

```
{ v1 [\CircleTimes] v1, v1 [\CircleTimes] v2, v2 [\CircleTimes] v1, v2 [\CircleTimes] v2 },
```

and so on.

I have written the following code:

```
TensorBasis[labels_, d_] := Module[
   {dim = Length[labels], basis, j, k, indexlist, tmp},

   basis = ConstantArray[0, dim^d];
   tmp = ConstantArray[0, d];

   For[j = 1, j <= dim^d, j++,
   (* Indexlist stores the indices of the jth element of the basis for the d-fold tensor product  *)

   indexlist = InverseLex[dim, d, j];

   (* tmp holds the list of individual factors that will make up the jth element of the basis *)
    For[k = 1, k <= d, k++,
      tmp[[k]] = labels[[indexlist[[k]] ]]
    ];

   (* jth element of the basis is created by tensoring together all elements of tmp *)
    basis[[j]] = Infix[tmp, "\[CircleTimes]"]
  ];
Return[basis]
];
```

The function InverseLex just gives me the appropriate list of indices for the basis element I am trying to construct.  I am sure that that function is working properly.  But the output is all weird.  The problem is that in the output, the [CircleTimes] (i.e. tensor product) symbol is replaced by some junk: in Plain Text form it is

```
{Subscript[v, 1]â Subscript[v, 1],Subscript[v, 1]â Subscript[v, 2],Subscript[v, 2]â Subscript[v, 1],Subscript[v, 2]â Subscript[v, 2]}
```

When I use the Infix notation with "[CircleTimes]" otherwise it works fine.  Why won't it work inside this function?

Comment: With mma v8.0.4.0 in Windows your code gives the expected output. You can also try using `basis[[j]] = CircleTimes[Sequence @@ tmp]]`.

Comment: Mma 8.0.1.0 on OSX also gives the desired output. Maybe you have a font issue.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps it's a Linux issue then if it's working ok on Windows and Mac....

Comment: @kguler, your advice worked.  Thanks!  I am pretty new to Mathematica and didn't know about the `Sequence` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Infix` is only an output form. You most probably want the expression which you'd get when typing `v1 ⊗ v2` into Mathematica, which is entered with either `\[CircleTimes]` or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

As you can see by typing `v1 ⊗ v2 //FullForm`, this is `CircleTimes[v1, v2]`. The same is true for longer chains of `⊗`, i.e. `v1 ⊗ v2 ⊗ … ⊗ vn` has the internal form `CircleTimes[v1, v2, …, vn]`.

Also note that a complicated procedural code isn't necessary either, because Mathematica already brings the building blocks you need. Therefore the function you want should be written

```
TensorBasis[labels_List,d_Integer] := Outer[CircleTimes, Sequence@@Table[labels,{d}]]
```